# lodash break down array based on sub-array retaining the array record

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array like below. As you can see, a book can have many authors. But I want to group the book by an author. But regardless I want to get to break the array first so that the multiple authors will be broken down to a single author and the other one will go to create a new set of an array.

```
[0]
    'book_name': 'book1'
    'authors': array(1)
             0: 
                author_id:'value2'
                author_name: 'Name2'
[1]
    'book_name': 'book2'
    'authors': array(2)
             0: 
                author_id:'value1'
                author_name: 'Name1'
             1: 
                author_id:'value2'
                author_name: 'Name2'
```

I want to have expected output like this

```
[0]
    'book_name': 'book1'
    'authors': array(1)
             0: 
                author_id:'value2'
                author_name: 'Name2'
[1]
    'book_name': 'book2'
    'authors': array(1)
             0: 
                author_id:'value1'
                author_name: 'Name1'
[2]
    'book_name': 'book2'
    'authors': array(1)
             0: 
                author_id:'value2'
                author_name: 'Name2'
```

What I have done so far is:

```
 grouping = _.chain(books)
            .flatMap('authors')
            .groupBy('author_id')
            .value()
```

My solution actually works since it flattens the array, but my problem is that it only returns the 'authors', I want also to retrieve the 'books' information.

Comment: Can you paste real JS objects and not console output? It's easier to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need `lodash` to achieve the result you're expecting:

```js
const books = [
  {
    'book_name': 'book1',
    'authors': [
      {
        author_id: 'value2',
        author_name: 'Name2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'book_name': 'book2',
    'authors': [
      {
        author_id: 'value1',
        author_name: 'Name1',
      },
      {
        author_id: 'value2',
        author_name: 'Name2',
      }
    ],
  },
];

const transformed = books.reduce((accumulator, book) => {
  const authors = book.authors.map(author => ({
      ...book,
      authors: [author]
  }));

  return accumulator.concat(authors);
}, []);

console.log('original', books);
console.log('transformed', transformed);
```

Comment: one more question what if in books I have many array fields. How do I add the entire book field without identifying each like book_name: book.book_name, book_color:array(), book_page, etc

Comment: I've updated my solution. In few words - instead of enumerating all the properties you can use a `spread` object syntax `{...book}` so that it creates a shallow copy of the object. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score -1):

It can be done with simple JavaScript.

```
const books = [{    'book_name': 'book1',
    'authors': [{author_id:'value2',
                author_name: 'Name2'}] },
   {'book_name': 'book2',
    'authors': [{author_id:'value3',
                author_name: 'Name3'},
                {author_id:'value4',
                author_name: 'Name4'}] }];

const arr = [];
books.map((book)=>{ 
    book.authors.forEach((author) => {
        arr.push({ 
               book_name: book.book_name,
               authors: [author]   
         }); 
       }); 
     })
console.log(arr);
```